# Spring MVC Angular Js integration without template engine

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I would like to integrate Spring MVC with Angular JS without any Template Engine

I checked a few answers, but I could not resolve it . Below I have listed Xml,Controller and Html files. What I am missing here exactly?

**app-Servlet.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.angular.app" />
    <resources mapping="/views/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value="" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
            return "home.html";
    }
     @RequestMapping(value="/app/welcome",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody String welcome() {     
         logger.info("entering into original controller");
         System.out.println("entering into original controller");

         String text="Hello World!!!! Welcome";

      return text;

     }
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="">
        <div>
            Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        </div>
        <p ng-bind="name"></p>
        <div ng-controller="helloworldcontroller">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function helloworldcontroller($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/app/welcome").success(
                    function(response) {
                        $scope.title = response;
                        alert("sucess");
                    });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on some projects using the architecture Spring MVC + AngularJs and can give you feedback about:

You are trying to control the routes of html pages through the Spring MVC Contollers and I think this is not the best approach, since the AngularJs has its own engine to control routes and pages through the ng-route or ui-router.

In architectures of my projects work with a Spring MVC project providing a whole REST API to be consumed by a web AngularJs application.

The project structure is as follows:

```
parent-maven-project: 
|_project-core: Have all bussiness logic, data source config, persistence config, Services, Repositories, Entities, etc. 
|_project-web: Have a angularJs App (that controls the html pages routing using ui-router), API REST (Spring MVC Controllers) to be consumed and give the business layer access (project-core). 
|_project-ear: Pack core and web projects to deploy on JBoss EAP 6.2
```

In Spring MVC REST layer (project-web) | set up a Spring OAuth2 server that is used to authenticate users and make the session & access control through Spring Security. When the user logs into the application, the angularjs application receives an access token Bearer that is used to make the user requests during all the time that he remain logged in. All REST services are in request scope, are stateless, then the token is used to retrieve the Spring Security session and make all user access validation.